# Why is object.ray_cast() always returning the index of the face it was cast from?

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to cast a ray from a center of a polygon in an object using `object.ray_cast().` However, for some reason `ray_cast` always returns result with the `face_index` of the polygon I cast it from (cast from `polygon.center`). What can be the reason for this weird issue and is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: Posting your script may shed some light .

Comment: Actually figured out thanks to mont29 and other people on #blendercoders IRC. Casting a ray from a center of the polygon will always return this polyghon. Requires an offset in the direction of normal by minimum float diff value (epsilon).